# Hardlinking Git Repo for Deployment: Possible Downsides?

Tags: git, linux, server

I've got a production server I'm managing right now, but it's becoming incredibly inefficient to either:

1. SSH into the remote server, and develop server-side
2. Develop on my local machine and transfer changes to remote server

A possible remedy that came to mind was keeping a git repo that mirrored the filesystem of the remote-server (so the server's /var/www/html/ would be REPO/var/www/html), and then on push, having a git hook hardlink all of the files to their appropriate directories. Everything I'm currently pushing is just configs(e.g Nginx.conf)/interpreted files (e.g HTML/JS), so I don't see any issues popping up there. Even for compiled items, it seems to be as simple as using the same CPU architecture, during building, and then relinking server-side.

Am I missing something? I see only benefits here.

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: @gnat Fixed. Is this compliant?

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of automation to ease this process?  Git is a source control system, not a Continuous Deployment system.  It's probably the wrong tool for this.

Comment: It seems you're actually looking for something like SFTP or rsync, not a version control repository. Those two protocols can use SSH as a transport.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was considering CIs like Travis/Jenkins/Concourse, but they seem like overkill for something that I can achieve with a small githook/bash script. I don't need to build or test anything, besides what I run on my end.

Comment: @amon I was using SFTP/FTP for integration, but it's cumbersome with a very deep filesystem. I'll take a look into rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you have to ssh to your prod box, your automation has failed" (q).

Consider:

- `rsync`/`lsyncd` for immediate feedback (if you can't run enough things locally);
- a [git post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on push [to do something when you push a branch](https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9691385) to a repo [hosted](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) on your "prod" machine (it's trivial);
- [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_getting_started.html) for more complex workflows that e.g. involve restarting services, and general sanity.